# python: importing class from another file

Tags: python, oop

I have 2 files, one named `data.py` and the other `main.py`

Code data.py:

```
class data24:
    w = 75
```

code main.py:

```
import data    
lala = data24
print(lala.w)
```

It is giving me two errors: 'data' imported but unused and 'data24' undefined.

I've already put an empty **init**.py file in the directory.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, it is printing the correct information.

Answer (score 2):

For your own sake, please go over a basic Python tutorial. 
There are several basic errors in your code.

1. You probably meant `w` to be an instance attribute, so it should be initialized in an `__init__` method.
2. `data24` is undefined. You need to specify that it comes from `data`.

   ```
   data.data24
   ```
3. In order to initialize an instance you need to use `()`.

```
class data24:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = 75
```

```
import data    

lala = data.data24()
print(lala.w)
```

Comment: I wouldn't make an assumption that `w` should be an instance attribute. Maybe it is desired to be a class attribute. Nevertheless it is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

data24 is a class. To use it you need to create an object of it first.

like so `lala = data24()`

now `lala` is an instance of `data24`. You can now do operations on it.

Comment: `data24()` will still cause an error "data24 is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse the code in your `main.py` and find the error:

```
import data
```

Here you have imported `data`.
After that you declare a variable `lala`:

```
lala = data24
```

But where `data24` comes from? It comes from `data`. If you want to call it you have to adjust that line to:

```
lala = data.data24
```

Now it should work, but maybe not as you have expected. That is because you're assigning the class `data24` to `lala`. Maybe you rather like to instantiate an object like `data.data24()`.